# Akka Rest Server Jackson ObjectReader and ObjectWriter Initialization

Tags: akka, jackson-databind

I am using jackson ObjectReader and ObjectWriter object for serialization and deserialization in Akka Rest Server. 
I am getting byteString in the request and deserialize it to object. Below is the scala code for it.

```
val a = objectReader.readValue[java.util.List[Base[Long]]](request.toArray)
```

Base class is an abstract class and I can have multiple implementation of it

```
@JsonTypeInfo(use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME,
property = "impl")
@JsonSubTypes({
        @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = A.class, name = "A")
})
public abstract class Base<T> implements Serializable {
    private String impl;
    private ResponseStatus status;


    public String getImpl() {
        return impl;
    }

    public void setImpl(String impl) {
        this.impl = impl;
    }

    public void setStatus(ResponseStatus status) {
        this.status = status;
    }

    public ResponseStatus getStatus() {
        return status;
    }

    public static class ResponseStatus implements Serializable {
        private ReturnCode code;
        private String msg;

        public void setCode(ReturnCode code) {
            this.code = code;
        }

        public void setMsg(String msg) {
            this.msg = msg;
        }

        public ReturnCode getCode() {
            return code;
        }

        public String getMsg() {
            return msg;
        }
    }
}
```

How ever I have observed that first call for readValue and writeValueAsBytes takes long. 
I tried initializing it. But still it is not improving in Akka Execution Context. Anyone know the solution of it? Please help.